# How to collide with walls in Python Turtle maze app

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a labyrinth and I am moving my turtle with arrow keys using the `turtle.onkeypress()` function. I want it to not move if my next move is a wall.

`ts` is length of a single wall. `mur` means wall.

```
def gauche():
    if (typeCellule(a, b, turtle.xcor()-ts/2, turtle.ycor(), ts, liste1) == 'mur'):
        turtle.speed(0)
        turtle.color("red")
        print("wall on left")
    else:
        turtle.color("black")
        turtle.speed(120)
        turtle.setheading(180)
        turtle.forward(ts/2)
        print("gauche ; left")
def droite():
    if (typeCellule(a, b, turtle.xcor()+ts/2, turtle.ycor(), ts, liste1) == 'mur'):
        turtle.speed(0)
        turtle.color("red")
        print("mur a droite")
    else:
        turtle.color("black")
        turtle.speed(120)
        turtle.setheading(0)
        turtle.forward(ts/2)
        print("droite ; right")


def bas():
    if (typeCellule(a, b, turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()-ts/2, ts, liste1) == 'mur'):
        turtle.speed(0)
        turtle.color("red")
        print("mur en bas")
    else:
        turtle.color("black")
        turtle.speed(120)
        turtle.setheading(270)
        turtle.forward(ts/2)
        print("bas ; down")


def haut():
    if (typeCellule(a, b, turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()+ts/2, ts, liste1) == 'mur'):
        turtle.speed(0)
        turtle.color("red")
        print("mur en haut")
    else:
        turtle.color("black")
        turtle.speed(120)
        turtle.setheading(90)
        turtle.forward(ts/2)
        print("haut ; up")


# key bindings
turtle.onkeypress(gauche)
turtle.onkeypress(droite, "Right")
turtle.onkeypress(haut, "Up")
turtle.onkeypress(bas, "Down")
turtle.listen()
```

With this code, when I am on a wall, it turns red but it doesn't stop moving.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This isn't quite a [mcve]. Please add enough code so that I can run and see the problem. Thanks.